# Terragrunt plan-all auto-init doesn't seem to be working

Tags: terragrunt

I'm running into an issue where running `terragrunt plan-all` is requiring me to run a "terragrunt init" first .. reading https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/auto-init/#auto-init .. it says that it should "auto-init", but that doesn't seem to be happening..  I'm using v0.23.31 .. am I reading the auto-init feature wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few known cases where auto-init fails to detect a change. See [this issue](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/936#issuecomment-548458738).

Comment on #936: Auto-init is not working

Are you using any of the following in the terragrunt source?

- Local references (e.g source = ../module)
- Remote references with no ref tag
- Remote references with a ref tag that is a branch

In each of these cases, Auto Init is known to not work correctly. At a high level, the underlying mechanism is checking for changes in the source tag to decide when to run init.